# How do I query for gatsby-image?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, prismic.io, gatsby-image

I am trying to query a prismic single type to display photos via gatsby-image. After messing around in GraphiQL, I see the image url but I'm not sure how to plug it in to gatsby-image. Any advice? [image]

```
  <Layout 
    location={`home`}
    image={data.prismic._allDocuments.edges.node.hero_image.childImageSharp.fluid}
  >
```

Comment: Does this help - https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#how-to-use?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime you see the prefix `all` in GraphQL you should assume that it will return an array of things.

In `GraphQL` we can see that `_allDocuments.edges` returns an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of `edges`. If we want to display everything in that array, we need to map over it.

If we know the index of the single thing we want, we can access it directly with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties).

```
// ./pages/index.js

import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"


const IndexPage = ({data}) => {
  return (
  <Layout>
    <ul>
      {data.allFile.edges.map((edge) => (
        <li>{edge.node.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </Layout>
)}

export default IndexPage


export const query = graphql`
  query HomePageQuery {
    allFile(filter: {relativePath: {regex: "/png$/"}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          relativePath
          publicURL
          childImageSharp {
            fixed(width: 111) { 
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

---

Then you can just `import Img from "gatsby-image"` and pass the relevant queried value to the `<Img />` component's fixed or fluid prop.

```
// ./pages/index.js

import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Img from "gatsby-image"


const IndexPage = ({data}) => {
  return (
  <Layout>
      {data.allFile.edges.map((edge) => (
        <Img fixed={edge.node.childImageSharp.fixed} />
      ))}
  </Layout>
)}

export default IndexPage



export const query = graphql`
  query HomePageQuery {
    allFile(filter: {relativePath: {regex: "/png$/"}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          relativePath
          publicURL
          childImageSharp {
            fixed(width: 111) { 
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```